# manufacturing ambiguous data set

Tags: probability, mathematical-optimization, ambiguous, estimation, hyperparameters

I hope questions like this belong here. 
So here is the problem I am dealing with right now: 
I have some data collected from a manufacturing process (sensor data, process parameters etc.) and for every part that leaves the production line i know if it is scrap or not.
So for each part I have the its process data and the quality (0: good 1:bad)

My goal is to optimize the manufacturing process, i.e. find the optimal process parameters to produce the least amount of scrap.

What i did so far: I tried different classification algorithms (random forest, SVM, neural network) but none are able to achieve a good accuracy. 
I think the reason is that the data is very ambiguous, i.e if i have parts with the same process parameters some of them might be scrap while some might be good. But there is definitely a connection between quality and process parameters. 
What i want to now is to predict the "probability" for a part to be good or bad. Imo i want to estimate the probability density? Can i do this with K-nearest neighbours?

Answer (score 0):

A step you could try is to, for each parameter, estimate [image], where x is the parameter value and [image] is the good/bad indicator variable.

There's a chance that [image] does not adhere to any particular distribution, and not knowing the type of values they take on it would be hard for me to make a suggestion.

A "model free" approach would be to, given a set of n observations [image], "discretize" the parameter x so that [image]

Then you can estimate the pmf via

[image]

and similarly for the "bad" case.

After you have [image] for each parameter, you can compute the relative entropy/KL divergence between that parameter's "good" and "bad" cases. Those that have larger divergence between the two classes are the parameters that matter most, and their pmfs will hopefully show you which values are indicative of bad performance.

This is of course assuming the paramters iid, which they may in fact not be, but a similar process can be performed by considering co-parameters that are not independent and discretizing accordingly.